# Importing a Sketch file from Invision to computer

Tags: sketch-app, invision-studio

Is it possible to import a Sketch file that has been uploaded to an Invision prototype from a different computer than the original upload? I have tried doing with the Craft with no luck.

The scenario is this:

- Colleague uploads a Sketch file to Invision
- Colleague then invites me as a collaborator to the project

How do I then get that Sketch file *from* Invision to work on?

Comment: isn't it easier to just ask your colleague the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not possible to download Sketch file from Invision.
You can only download the prototype (screens and assets) in PDF or zip format from Invision.

Source: [Exports - Invision support](https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000635286)